# Linux command to edit zip file generated from numpy savez function

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I want to edit zip file generated by numpy savez function. For example we can make a zip file like

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> y = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> dat = {'/path/to/x': x, '/path/to/y': y}
>>> f = open('foo', 'wb')
>>> np.savez(f, **dat)
```

This code creates a zip file named foo. (On ubuntu GUI, it is shown as Zip archive type)

Then, I want to remove the file y in the zip file. (Without using Python)

I have tried an approach that first unzip the file and manually remove the file and zip it again. I made a zip file by `tar` command, but it generates gzip-compressed tar archive.

What is the correct way to edit and generate zip file generated by numpy save_z?

Comment: if you use `unzip` then you should check `zip` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-d` option from the `zip` command like this:

```
zip foo -d y
```

This will delete file `y` from the zip file `foo`.

You can check the files stored in the zip file with `unzip -l foo` to check the full path and names of the files stored in `foo`.

Comment: Hi, Alvaro. Thank you. The command works me, but I had to rename `foo` to `foo.zip`.   Is there an option to work without this renaming?

Comment: `zip` is based on old windows code (7-Zip), and thus might be more rigid about file extensions than native UNIX.

Comment: Any clues in the extended help?  `zip -h2`?

Comment: @ywat I think it will always add a `.zip` extension unless the file has another extension already, ex: `foo.foo`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the archive manager; in my case the `Mate` version, `Engrampa`.

I got an error when I tried to delete a file from from a `.npz` file.  But if I renamed it to `.zip` the delete worked fine.  And `np.load` handled the `zip` name.

An `npz` file is `p7zip Version 9.20`; this is a different archive format than the 'native' unix, `gzipped tar`.  A modern linux archive manager can handle these and others, depending on which commandline tools are installed.